# How to remove storage item(vector data) automatically after a time interval?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node-template

I'm storing a vector of struct data inside a StorageValue, like this..

```
StorageValue<_, BoundedVec<RootClubForm<T>, T::MaxValue>, ValueQuery>;
```

Is there any way I can automatically remove data from the storage value based on a time Interval, for ex: I want to remove data older than 10 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

No there is no automatic way to do this. You would need to implement this on your own. Something like the following should work:

```
fn on_initialize(now: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
    if now % MY_INTERVAL == 0 {
        // your clean up logic
    }
}
```

Here you would use the `on_initialize` hook that is called for each block at initialization. Then you would check if your clean up interval has passed to run your clean up code. If it is only about deleting on `StorageValue`, it should be fine. However, if you start doing any kind iteration you need to ensure that you will not touch too many storage elements.

Comment: Perfect....Thank you